# MySQL getting results from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm looking in how I can merge these two queries into one.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = 'email';
SELECT * FROM organisations WHERE email = 'email';
```

On my website we use an email address as username. It should be possible to login with a username you have signed up with as an organization as well as a username you have signed up with as a customer.

One cannot create a customer account with the same email address that is already associated with an organization account and vice versa.

Thanks in advance, Sander

Comment: Use `UNION [ALL]`

Comment: What *results* do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd like to get all the collumns of the table where the email address checkes out.

Answer (score 0):

$email = examplemail

SELECT * FROM customers, organisations WHERE (customers.email = '$email' AND organisations.email = '$email')

Comment: I tried it (kinda) this way, but the mistake I made was that I put an 'OR' statement instead of an 'AND' statement because it seemed more logical to me for some reason. Will test out your sugestion ASAP :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make it one table for both and add a new column named isOrganization which is 1 for people who are sign up as organization members and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Add the same like this

```
SELECT * FROM customers, organisations WHERE customers.email = organisations.email AND customers.email = '$email'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if an email is valid, you could do:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customers WHERE email = 'email')
             THEN 'customer'
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM organisations WHERE email = 'email')
             THEN 'organization'
        END) as match_type;
```

A `NULL` value means there is no match.